# vue.js multiple transitions for a router-view

Tags: transition, vue.js, vue-router

If I have a vue-router 'router-view' element defined like this:

`<router-view transition="slide">`

Is there a way to change the transition to a 'fade' when a specific route is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dynamic binding fopr transition:

```
<router-view :transition="$route.transition">
```

And set the data of transition from your route data

```
router.map({
  '/specialroute': {
    component: { ... },
    transition: 'fade'
  }
})
```