# Vue.js page transition fade effect with vue-router

Tags: transition, fade, effect, vue-router, vue.js

How to achieve a fade effect page transition between vue-router defined pages (components)?

Comment: I found the following link very helpful in setting this up on my project: https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/vue-router-page-transitions/

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Wrap `<router-view></router-view>` with `<transition name="fade"></transition>` and add these styles:

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.fade-enter-active {
  transition-delay: .25s;
}

.fade-enter, .fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0
}
```

**Detailed answer**

Assuming you have created your application with vue-cli, e.g.:

```
vue init webpack fadetransition
cd fadetransition
npm install
```

Install the router:

```
npm i vue-router
```

If you are not developing your app using vue-cli, make sure to add the vue router the standard way:

```
<script src="/path/to/vue.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/vue-router.js"></script>
```

You can use e.g.: https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js

The CLI has created a backbone application for you, which you can add components to.

**1) Create page components**

In Vue, components (UI elements) can be nested. A page in your app can be made with a regular Vue component that is considered as the root to other components in that page.

Go to `src/` and create `pages/` directory. These page-root components (individual pages) will be put in this directory, while the other components used in the actual pages can be put to the ready-made `components/` directory.

Create two pages in files called `src/pages/Page1.vue` and `src/pages/Page2.vue` for starters. Their content will be (edit page numbers respectively):

```
<template>
  <h1>Page 1</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

**2) Setup routing**

Edit the generated `src/main.js` add the required imports:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Page1 from './pages/Page1'
import Page2 from './pages/Page2'
```

Add a global router usage:

```
Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

Add a router setup:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/page1', component: Page1 },
    { path: '/page2', component: Page2 },
    { path: '/', redirect: '/page1' }
  ]
})
```

The last route just redirects the initial path `/` to `/page1`. Edit the app initiation:

```
new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

The whole `src/main.js` example is at the end of the answer.

**3) Add a router view**

Routing is set up by now, just a place where the page components will be rendered according to the router is missing. This is done by placing `<router-view></router-view>` somewhere in the templates, you will want to put it in the `src/App.vue`'s `<template>` tag.

The whole `src/App.vue` example is at the end of the answer.

**4) Add fade transition effect between page components**

Wrap the `<router-view></router-view>` with a `<transition name="fade">` element, e.g.:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <transition name="fade">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

Vue will do the job here: it will create and insert appropriate CSS classes starting with the name specified through-out the effect's duration, e.g.: `.fade-enter-active`. Now define the effects in App.vue's  section:

```
<style>
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.fade-enter-active {
  transition-delay: .25s;
}

.fade-enter, .fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0
}
</style>
```

That's it. If you run the app now, e.g. with `npm run dev`, it will automatically display Page 1 with a fade-in effect. If you rewrite the URL to /page2, it will switch the pages with fade-out and fade-in effects.

Check out the documentation on [routing](https://router.vuejs.org/en/) and [transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html) for more information.

**5) Optional: Add links to pages.**

You can add links to particular pages with the `<router-link>` component, e.g.:

```
<router-link to="/page1">Page 1</router-link>
<router-link to="/page2">Page 2</router-link>
```

This automatically gives the links a `router-link-active` class in case they are active, but you can also specify custom classes if you are using e.g. Bootstrap:

```
<router-link class="nav-link" active-class="active" to="/page1">Page 1</router-link>
<router-link class="nav-link" active-class="active" to="/page2">Page 2</router-link>
```

**Files for reference**

src/main.js:

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

import App from './App'
import Page1 from './pages/Page1'
import Page2 from './pages/Page2'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/page1', component: Page1 },
    { path: '/page2', component: Page2 },
    { path: '/', redirect: '/page1' }
  ]
})

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

src/App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-link class="nav-link" active-class="active" to="/page1">Page 1</router-link>
    <router-link class="nav-link" active-class="active" to="/page2">Page 2</router-link>
    <transition name="fade">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app'
}
</script>

<style>
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.fade-enter-active {
  transition-delay: .25s;
}

.fade-enter, .fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0
}
</style>
```

src/pages/Page1.vue:

```
<template>
  <h1>Page 1</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

src/pages/Page2.vue:

```
<template>
  <h1>Page 2</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify which transition to use for each page? For example, I am trying to move the page up / down based on which page that user is navigating to/from.

Comment: @SoichiHayashi This approach could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776733/vue-js-multiple-transitions-for-a-router-view?rq=1

Comment: @SoichiHayashi Have a look here too https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/transitions.html#per-route-transition

Comment: Can it be that the effect does not work routing on the same component through watch?

Answer (score 2):

## Plug and Play Solution

There is also a plug and play solution called `vue-page-transition` which offers you all sort of `transitions`. (fade, flip, zoom, overlay etc.)

**1 - Install the npm package:**

```sh
yarn add vue-page-transition
```

**2 - register the plugin:**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VuePageTransition from 'vue-page-transition'

Vue.use(VuePageTransition)
```

**3 - wrap your `router-view` with the global animation:**

```html
<vue-page-transition name="fade-in-right">
  <router-view/>
</vue-page-transition>
```

Learn more on GitHub:
https://github.com/Orlandster/vue-page-transition